# SQL Server query with same functionality as Excel VLookup with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
select 
b.columnb,
case when a.columna is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end 
from
tableb b left outer join
tablea a on b.columnb = a.columna
```

in above query, how can i include one more condition to see only 'False' values?

thanks.

Comment: its dynamically added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `WHERE` to your [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement:

```
select 
b.columnb,
case when a.columna is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end 
from
 tableb b 
 left outer join tablea a on (b.columnb = a.columna)
WHERE a.columna IS NULL;
```

In which case you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT
b.columnb,
'FALSE'
FROM
 tableb b 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tablea a ON (b.columnb = a.columna)
WHERE a.columna IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can:

- Put in a WEHERE condition at the end that filders a.columna is null
  OR
- Wrap all that into another select where the field (that you must name - the case should emit a name for that field) is filtered by FALSE. You can use any SELECT Statement instead of a table name in SQL Server at least.